# Nesting directives within directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Regarding AngularJS directives I've ran into a situation where I'm calling a directive from within another directive and I have the following questions.

1. Why can't I referecne scope.bindValue in my link function? Is there a way I can compute a value from scope.bindValue and set it to scope?
2. Why can the subdirective bind using "@" in scope:{} but not use scope.value = attrs.value in the link function?

All of the below can be seen at http://jsfiddle.net/sdg9/AjDtt/13/

HTML:

```
<directive bind-value="12" value="7"></directive>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var commonTemplate = '<div>{{name}} bind-value is: {{bindValue}} </div><div>{{name}} value is: {{value}} </div><div>{{name}} add one to bind-value is: {{addOneBindValue}} </div><div>{{name}} add one to value is: {{addOneValue}} </div><br/>';

myApp.directive('directive', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            bindValue: "@",
        },
        template: commonTemplate + '<br/><sub-directive bind-value="{{value}}" value="{{value}}"></sub-directive>',
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.name = "Directive";
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.addOneBindValue = parseInt(scope.bindValue) + 1;
            scope.addOneValue = parseInt(scope.value) + 1;
        }
    };
});


myApp.directive('subDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            bindValue: "@"
        },
        template: commonTemplate,
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {   
            scope.name = "SubDirective";
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.addOneBindValue = parseInt(scope.bindValue) + 1;
            scope.addOneValue = parseInt(scope.value) + 1;
        }
    };
});
```

Output:

```
Directive bind-value is: 12
Directive value is: 7
Directive add one to bind-value is: null    <--- why?
Directive add one to value is: 8    

SubDirective bind-value is: 7
SubDirective value is:                      <--- why?
SubDirective add one to bind-value is: null
SubDirective add one to value is: null
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Interpolated attributes (i.e., attributes that use {{}}s) and isolate scope properties defined with '@' are not available when the link function runs.  You need to use `attrs.$observe()` (or `scope.$watch( @ property here, ...)`) to get the values (asynchronously).

So, `scope.bindValue` is not available when you are trying to use it.

Similarly, in your subDirective, attribute `value` has {{}}s, so its value will also not be available when you are trying to use it.  You also need to define an '@' directive property for this.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/rTsxt/).

The reason for the asynchronous requirement is that the items inside the {{}}s may change, and you normally want your directive to notice (and then do something -- like update the "addOne" values).  '@' is normally used with isolate scopes when the attribute value contains {{}}s.

If attribute values are constants, and you're not going to use the values in a template (or templateUrl), then '@' probably shouldn't be used.  In the link function, just use `attrs.attrName` if the value is a string, or `scope.$eval(attrs.attrName)` if the attribute is a number or boolean (or `parseInt(attrs.attrName)` if you know it is a number).

Comment: Thanks was able to get this working with attrs.$observe().  I'll stick to using '@' on the subdirective as that should be sufficient for my scenarios.   http://jsfiddle.net/sdg9/AjDtt/16/

Comment: @Steven, I was creating a fiddle the same time you were :)  In my fiddle, I also show how to get `value` into the subDirective.  I also updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: regarding "If attribute values are constants, '@' probably shouldn't be used" what about when I am nesting directives?  My outermost directive may look like <directive value="7"></directive> but since it's using a templateURL it is calling my sub directive via an interpolated attribute.  Is this the correct use of templateURL or should I be constructing the element myself via angular.element and adding it to the template? The later feels like a lot of extra work to me to avoid interpolated attributes.