# Is it possible to load a Directive in a Directive with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement the http://logicbomb.github.io/ng-directives/drag-drop.html directive. I have another directive I'm trying to include it in...

```
angular.module('MyApp') 
  .directive('seconddirective', function ($rootScope, $lvlDraggable) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
```

but that doesn't work... so is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to this:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2471-Delegating-Nested-Directive-Behavior-To-Parent-Directive-In-AngularJS.htm

or this:
[Nesting directives within directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438837/nesting-directives-within-directives)